# How to write a macro which gets runtime of a function?

Tags: c, macros, posix, timeval

Suppose we want to know how long function A runs, we can write code like this

```
    struct timeval tpstart,tpend;  
    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL); 
    A(); 
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL); 
    float timeuse= tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec + (tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec) / 1000000; 
    printf("Used Time:%f\n",timeuse);
```

But how can I encapsulate it to a MACRO such Runtime(A), perhaps, Runtime(A, B, ...), sometime s several functions run together.

Comment: `gettimeofday` is not standard C and also declared obsolete by POSIX, consider using `clock_gettime` from POSIX or `timespec_get` from C11.

Comment: Ok, it's a code segment I derived by google, I never use it before

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the function's return value, life is easy:

```
#define Runtime(x)  do { \
    struct timeval tpstart,tpend;  \
    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);   \
    x; \
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL); \
    float timeuse= tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec + (float)(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec) / 1000000; \
    printf("Used Time:%f\n",timeuse); \
} while(0)

Runtime( A() );
Runtime( A() ; B() );
```

Comment: You could even be more informative with `#x ": Used Time: %f"`.

Comment: however when use Runtime(cudaKernel<<<1,1>>>()); it fails

Comment: @stonestrong, it looks that you are using CUDA? Be careful, other than you may think, CUDA is not C but C++. The preprocessor easily gets confused by C++ with differing syntax rules. Here in particular the comma in `1,1` is interpreted by the preprocessor as separation of macro arguments. To cope with that change the `#define` to `Runtime(...)`, three dots, and use `__VA_ARGS__`, two underscores infront and behind, in the place of `x`.

Comment: @JensGustedt, an extra pair of parentheses can also help - `Runtime((cudaKernel<<<1,1>>>()));` - this way the macro knows it's only one parameter. But your variation of the macro is indeed more usable.